# How to show Specified number of events in full calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery full calendar. I have more than 150 events in a day.

When i am showing all the events then full calendar is not looking good.

In the week view of full calendar all the events are fully overlapped and it results very bad look.

Now i want to show only the specified number of events on the calendar in a day.

I' d like to have a parameter that allow me to indicate the maximum events
that can be showed into a day of the month view. If a day has more than 2
or 3 events, the rendering is not so good (long list of events that stretch
the calendar). When more than 2 or 3 events are rendered, a special div
should show a text like the following "..more events.." and user can see
other events by clicking on this div (also for example going to the day view)

How i can do this.

Thanks,
Rajbir

Answer (score 1):

The issue was talked at http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=304.

And they added a feature named limitEvents, you can check demo at: https://github.com/lyconic/fullcalendar/blob/master/demos/limit-events.html

```
.events({ ... }).limitEvents(3);
```